# Counting incongruent isometric factorizations in the ring of integers of a number field with non-trivial class group

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, factorization-theory

Let $H$ be a multiplicatively written commutative monoid. We use $\mathcal A(H)$ for the set of atoms of $H$ and $\pi_H$ for the canonical homomorphism $\mathscr F(\mathcal A(H)) \to H$, where $a \in H$ is called an *atom* if it is not a unit and doesn't split into the product of two non-units, and $\mathscr F(\mathcal A(H))$ is the free abelian monoid with basis $\mathcal A(H)$, whose operation I'll denote by $\ast$.

Given $x \in H$, we set $\mathscr Z_H(x) := \pi_H^{-1}(x)$. We refer to the elements of $\mathscr Z_H(x)$ as the *factorizations* of $x$ (relative to the atoms of $H$), and we say that two (non-empty) factorizations $\mathfrak a = a_1 \ast \cdots \ast a_m$ and $\mathfrak b = b_1 \ast \cdots \ast b_n$ of $x$ of lengths $m$ and $n$, respectively, are *congruent* if $m = n$ and there is a permutation $\sigma$ of $[\![1,m]\!]$ such that $b_{\sigma(i)} \in H^\times a_i H^\times$ for each $i$, in which case we write $\mathfrak a \sim_x \mathfrak b$. As a matter of fact, $\sim_x$ is an equivalence on the set $\mathscr Z_H(x)$, and here comes my question:

> **Q.** Assume $H$ is the multiplicative monoid of the ring of integers of a number field with non-trivial (ideal) class group, and let $m \in \mathbf N^+$. Does there exist $x \in H$ such that $|\mathscr Z_H(x)/\sim_x| = m$ and the factorizations of $x$ have all the same length?

Note that, in the scope of the question, the quotient $\mathscr Z_H(x)/\sim_x$ is a non-empty, finite subset of $\mathbf N^+$ for every non-unit $x \in H$, and the class group being non-trivial implies that, for each $m \in \mathbf N^+$, there exists $x \in H$ with $|\mathscr Z_H(x)/\sim_x| \ge m$.

*Added later.* I don't have a well-defined motivation for the question. By and large, I'm looking for a more accurate "measure" of the "distance from the condition of factoriality" than the one provided by classical invariants such as [systems of sets lengths](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.10.960).